# Cassandra, query the primary key, skipping the clustering column (timeuuid)

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, datastax

Please am still new using Cassandra i have an issue which i want to solve yet have tried but i couldn't.

I want to get all users who like a particular post and all the posts that a particular user likes and I have a like and unlike button, when the user click like button on a post i save the information to these tables, which is working but when the user click the unlike button how do i delete that particular row from these table below

```
CREATE TABLE social.post_likedby_user (
   userid bigint,
   timeuuid timestamp,
   postid bigint,
   content text,
   creation_date text,
   liked boolean,
   PRIMARY KEY (userid, timeuuid, postid)
)  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timeuuid DESC);

CREATE TABLE social.user_likeby_post (
   postid bigint,
   timeuuid timestamp,
   userid bigint,
   name text,
   username text,
   email text,
   phone text,
   birthday text,
   PRIMARY KEY (postid, timeuuid, userid)
)  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timeuuid DESC);
```

I have tried several query yet no result

```
DELETE FROM post_likedby_user WHERE userid = ? AND postid = ?
DELETE FROM user_likeby_post WHERE postid = ? AND userid = ?
```

How can i query this table without knowing the timeuuid. I think the problem is the timeuuid column and i don't want to use ALLOW FILTERING since i read about it that is not good for production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case we need one more table post_timeuuids:

```
CREATE TABLE social.post_timeuuids (
   userid bigint,
   postid bigint,
   timeuuid timestamp,
   PRIMARY KEY (userid, postid, timeuuid)
)
```

So to query timeuuid values you run query below:

```
select timeuuid from post_timeuuids where userid = ? and postid = ?;
```

now you can use these values to run delete queries:

```
DELETE FROM post_likedby_user WHERE userid = ? AND timeuuid = ? AND postid = ?
```

OR as an alternative instead of deleting you can just delete from "post_timeuuids" table. On application side you should consider data in "post_timeuuids": if no timestamps present there it means that uses don't have "likes" for that particular post.

Article below explain why you can't run your queries for post_likedby_user without your 'timeuuid' clustering key

https://rollerweblogger.org/roller/entry/composite_keys_in_cassandra

Comment: wow i never thought of that. Thank you @AlexBinkovsky this is awesome